# Zip multiple files with certain size limit for each Zip using Java

Tags: java, zip

Need to zip files (pdf format) in a folder to multiple zip files with 100 MB limit on the zip file size uing Java.

For eg.

> If the folder has 100 files with 10 MB each - so I would have to
>   create 10 zip files.

I have looked at different questions but nothing worked so far. I have the basic code to zip files in a folder but unable to get what's needed. Any help will be appreciate a lot.

Thanks

**EDIT: It may look like a duplicate question, but none of the solutions work. And that is an old thread. Hoping for newer solutions**

Comment: Why two different code examples with different libraries in the duplicated post don't work for you?

Comment: @KarolDowbecki yes. Tried them before posting